# Prove that there doesn't exists a holomorphic function on $U^c$ satisfying this particular condition

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying some questions in complex analysis and got struck upon this particular problem.

> Question: Prove that there doesn't exists a holomorphic function f on $U^c$ such that $|f(z)| \to \infty$ as $|z|\to 1$ .

**Edit**: U is open unit disc with center at origin .

I tried this problem by assuming that there exists such a holomorphic function and trying to find a contradiction.
But unfortunately I am unable to find what result should I use to contradict.

I am not good at solving problems in complex analysis but trying to learn.
Your help would be really appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: Which set is $U$?

Comment: What is $U$ ????

Comment: @Fred Kindly see edit.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos kindly see edit . I thought this notation was common so, I didn't included it.

Comment: Just an intuition, but maybe looking at $\frac{1}{f(1/z)}$ might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conisder $g=1/f$ so $g(z) \to 0, |z| \to 1, |z|>1$. By the reflection principle $g$ extends to a holomorphic function defined on a neighborhood of the unit circle so to a domain $|z| > 1-\delta, \delta >0$ which is zero on the unit circle; by the identity principle $g$ is $0$ everywhere, hence $f$ is infinity everywhere, contradiction!

Edit later - as asked a concrete way of extension is to take $g(w)=g(\frac{1}{w}), 0< |w| <1$; then $g$ is clearly analytic in the punctured unit disc and $g(w) \to 0, |w| \to 1, |w| \ne 1$;

extending $g(w)=0$ when $|w|=1$, gives us a continuous function $g$ on a domain $D$ that can be split as $D_1 \cup C \cup D_2$, $g$ analytic on the domains $D_1, D_2$ and $C$ a smooth Jordan curve that is a common intersection of (in general part of) the boundaries of $D_1$ and $D_2$; the symmetry principle says that $g$ is analytic on $D$ and the proof can be done using Morera but also using Cauchy which I prefer (note that the reflection principle usually refers to the case when $C$ is part of a circle/line indeed like here but the proof below works for any nice enough - eg rectifiable - Jordan curve and any $g$ with the stated hypothesis)

Proof of the symmetry principle using Cauchy:
pick some $|w|=1$ and a small circle arc $C_w$ containing it; make small domains $U_1 \subset D_1, U_2 \subset D_2$ by joing the ends of $C_w$ with small arcs $C_{1,2}$ contained in $D_{1,2}$ with same ends as $C_w$ and let $\Gamma_{1,2}$ the two closed paths (traversed counterclockwise) that are the boundary of $U_{1,2}$ and $g_{1,2}(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma_{1,2}}\frac{g(\zeta)d\zeta}{\zeta-z}$

Then by Cauchy $g_1(z)=g(z), z \in U_1, g_1(z)=0, z \in U_2$ and same for $g_2$ with roles reversed; adding them and noting that that $C_w$ is traversed in opposite directions so that part of the two integrals cancels out, we get that $g_1(z)+g_2(z)=\int_{\Gamma=C_1 \cup C_2}\frac{g(\zeta)d\zeta}{\zeta-z}$ is an analytic function in the domain that is bounded by $\Gamma$ and for which $w$ is now an interior point, while $g_1+g_2=g, |z| \ne 1$, hence by continuity $g_1+g_2=g, |z|=1$ so indeed $g$ is analytic at $w$ too!

Comment: If you are using Schwartz reflection principle then how does you that f is real for real z ? This assertion must be satisfied. Can you please explain?

Comment: gave you a short proof of the general symmetry (reflection) principle and how we use it here - Schwarz is a special case